# Inject HTML tags through a Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, inject

I'm searching for a method to inject some HTML tags into a page like youtube.com through my Firefox addon. I ported my Chrome extension into Firefox and changed some code. I know there is a way with the page-mod but every time the console log shows *"require is not a function"*.

But that's not the problem, I think my addon won't accept jQuery because one line looks like:

```
$('body').append("<button>some text</button>
```

and it does not inject this line. Can you help me pls? I inserted the jQuery through the `manifest.json` and in my Firefox's developer version it works fine but only the standard Firefox won't do that. 
And sorry that I can't show more Code because its a project from my work and I'm at home.

Comment: Your code, as written, is invalid.

Comment: What [kind of Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) are you making ([Overlay/XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions), [Restartless](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions), [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK), or [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions))? Please add the appropriate tag to your question.

Comment: @Makyen I'm making a WebExtension

Comment: You appear to have confused how to write a WebExtension with the Add-on SDK. You probably should review the tutorials: [Your first WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension) and [Your second WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension)

Comment: @Makyen yeah i'm confused. It is hard to develop a special firefox extension in three days. I never developed one for fireox and it is pretty hard.

Comment: So I checked everything. The code works fine if I execute it in a `popup.html`. It seems that Firefox cant execute my `browser.tabs.executeScript` from a backgroundfile or insert my html tags. Any ideas? Here is my execute Code for the insert function.


`var partnerInfo = this.getPartnerObjects(url);
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "js/lib/jQuery.js"}, function(){
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "js/marker.js"}, function(){
var jscode = topBonus.getData(partnerInfo) + "insertMarker(data);";
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: jscode}, function() {});
});
});`